# Alternative to as3isolib?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, linear-algebra

I've been working on a Flash game that involves an isometric space.  I've been using `as3isolib` for a while now, and I'm less than impressed with how easy it is to use.  Whether I'm approaching it the wrong way or it's just not that great to use is a question for another post.

Anyways, I've been thinking of a different way to approach the problem of isometric positions, and I think I've got an idea that might work.  Essentially, each object that is to be rendered to the iso-space maintains a 3-coordinate position.  Those items are then registered with a camera that projects that 3-coordinate position to a 2-coordinate point on the screen according to [the math on this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection#Mathematics).  Then, the MovieClip is added to the stage (or to the camera's MovieClip, perhaps) at that point, and at a child index of the point's y-value.  That way, I figure objects that are closer to the camera will be "above" the objects further away, and will get rendered over them.

So my question, then, is two-fold:

1. Do you think this idea will work the way I think it will?
2. Are there any existing 3D matrix/vector packages that I should look at?  I know there's a Matrix3 class in Flex 3, but we're not using Flex for this game.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same using other 3D library such as Papervision3D and Away3D. All you need to do is to apply orthogonal lens to the camera.

See 
[Doc here](http://away3d.com/livedocs/3.6.0_lib/away3d/cameras/lenses/OrthogonalLens.html)
and
[Tutorial](http://www.scribd.com/doc/54498653/135/Changing-camera-lenses)

Answer (score 2):

Hi Tedw4rd & any other potential as3isolib users

I am the developer of the as3isolib.v1 (currently working on v2).  Sorry this reply is so late but figured it would be beneficial to see a response from the developer.

Yes as3isolib.v1 is kinda slow and knowing HOW to implement it for the best performance is lacking.  If you are by chance still trying to work with the library, there is an official users group where I try to address each and every question http://bit.ly/jTlf18

Knowing how to construct your iso world is key to getting the best performance out of the v1 engine.

Comment: I just realized my user group digest emails have not been getting sent to me.  Working on that currently to resolve.Suffice it to say I or another user will address your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Rotate your view 45 degrees and apply 0.5 y-scale. this makes flash do the math for you. then you just need to solve the depth problem. for that i suggest you to read [this](http://ericlin2.tripod.com/iso/isoDepthOld5t.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish, but yes your idea of using the y value to determine the z-depth will work.

To answer your 2nd question, here is a link that may give you some options for other AS3 Isometric packages. This guy is a great developer.

http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/02/23/11-flash-isometric-engines-you-can-use-in-your-games/